# What's the error in the code.?

Tags: c

Okay..so the Question is ..assume it was monday on the 1st of january 2001 so..taking that as a reference...a YEAR is input by the keyboard,find out what is the day on the 1st january of that(input) year.

In my program(below)..when person types a input greater than the reference year(2001)..answer comes out to be correct but..if the input is less than 2001..than answer is coming wrong..
Can you please point out and explain the error in my code..
Thanks..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int present_year;
    int normal_days;
    int normal_year;
    int leap_year;
    int leap_days;
    int check;
    int total_days;
    int reference_year=2001;
    int day;

    printf("Enter the year you want to check\n");
    scanf("%d",&present_year);
    if(reference_year<present_year)

    /*if year entered is greater than reference year(2001)*/
    {
        check=present_year-reference_year;
    }

    if(present_year<reference_year)
    /* if year entered is smaller than reference year*/
    {
        check=reference_year-present_year;
    }

    leap_year=check/4;
    normal_year=check-leap_year;
    normal_days=normal_year*365;
    leap_days=leap_year*366;
    total_days=leap_days+normal_days;
    day=total_days%7;

    if(day==0)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Monday\n",present_year);
    if(day==1)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Tuesday\n",present_year);
    if(day==2)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Wednesday\n",present_year);
    if(day==3)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Thursday\n",present_year);
    if(day==4)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Friday\n",present_year);
    if(day==5)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Saturday\n",present_year);
    if(day==6)
        printf("January 1 of year %d will be Sunday\n",present_year);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if a user entered `2001` ? then you would use an uninitialized variable  in your code.

Comment: one note, leap_year needs more than just modulo 4, it needs both modulo 100 (not leap year) and modulo 400 (leap year) but if difference is small it works as is

Comment: you cant check for leap year by just dividing by `4` it will be by `400`

Comment: if present year is less that reference year (2001) use negative numbers or subtract, as is right now you always add days this is why it is wrong, plus the leap_year issue mentioned above

Comment: @varuntewari year 2000 was a leap year. You need to improve yourself. :P

Comment: @ Nikos M. why do i need to use modulo 100 for leap year..i am finding NUMBER of leap years...which can be found out by dividing (check)  by 4 and getting the quotient.

Comment: @harsher, check i40west's answer for clarification. This is the definition of a leap year. Itr is not just modulo 4 it also should not be modulo 100 but modulo 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to begin... do you even understand what a leap year is? I don't think that you do. It's *not* once every four years.

Here, try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

double mod(double x, double y)
{
    return x - y * floor(x / y);
}

bool gregorian_leap_year(int year)
{
    return (
        mod(year, 4) == 0 &&
        !(mod(year, 400) == 100 ||
          mod(year, 400) == 200 ||
          mod(year, 400) == 300)) ? true : false;
}

int fixed_from_gregorian(int year, int month, int day)
{
    int correction, f;
    if (month <= 2) correction = 0;
    else if (month > 2 && gregorian_leap_year(year)) correction = -1;
    else correction = -2;

    f = 365 * (year - 1) +
        floor((year - 1) / 4.0) -
        floor((year - 1) / 100.0) +
        floor((year - 1) / 400.0) +
        floor((367 * month - 362) / 12.0) +
        correction + day;
    return f;
}

char *daynames[] = {
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int present_year;
    printf("Enter the year you want to check\n");
    scanf("%d", &present_year);

    int f = fixed_from_gregorian(present_year, 1, 1);
    int day = (int)mod(f,7);

    printf("January 1 of year %d will be %s\n", present_year, daynames[day]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have initialized with 1 Jan 2001 while you can initialize it with 1 Jan 0001 which is Monday. And then simply find the odd days and calculate the day on 1 jan XXXX

```
odd_days=(year-1) + leap_years;
```

- Here *year* is the **user input**

and then

```
day=odd_days%7;
```

Comment: can you please explain, why did you do (year-1)?

Comment: `year-1` is because i want the difference between the year entered by user and year 0001.

Comment: if someone has to calculate the day for year 1003...it won't come right as 2%7 will give 0 so..i think we will have to calculate total no..of days and then divide by 7.

Comment: oops i forgot to mention. `**If odd_day<7 then day=odd_day**`

Comment: You need to calculate number of days only when you want to find the day of a date other than _1 jan_